# Using strip_tags for form validation with allowable_tags

Tags: codeigniter, validation, strip-tags

It appears I can use PHP's [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function within Codeigniter's form validation like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 
                              'trim|xss_clean|strip_tags');
```

Strip_tags supports an allowable_tags parameter to list tags to exclude from the filtering e.g. keep `<h1>`, `<strong>` etc.

How can I use this within the form validation syntax?

Comment: Why are you using `xss_clean` in tandem with `strip_tags` that's redundant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'callback_description_check');

public function direction_check($str)
{
    return strip_tags($text, '<p><a>'); 
}
```

Best way would be to create your own callback function, which you can modify according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

you could make a callback

```
function callback_strip_tags_custom($text)
{
 return strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');

}
```